# Roaming Profiles Log

Tags: roaming-profile

Is there a log somewhere that provides a log of what is going on and why all my roaming profiles are failing.  I have it set so that the user is the owner and has full control but each time I log off I get: "Windows cannnot update roaming profile" error.  I've looked in the users profile folder and there is nothing in there.

Thanks,
Noah

Comment: I just confirmed that is is a permissions issue.  When I go to the location: \\domain.local\Files\Profiles\TQUser and I'm logged in as TQUser, I can't create a file there.  Which is odd because I have full control/access of that folder as that user.  Any ideas on what else to check or take a look at.  I'm using DFS if that makes any difference.

Comment: What SHARE permissions are on the root share?

Comment: I went back and went to sharing and set Everyone to have full control.  That didn't do the trick, but I figured it would on the TQUser folder.  Or do I need to look at Profiles?

Comment: It was the Profiles folder.  I get it now the permissions i was messing with were local.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend looking in the event logs on the computer and seeing if there are any relevant events. You can also turn on user environment logging as per this article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/221833

Comment: I figured it out without using this, but it would have been helpful had the issue not been resolved.